# iPad 2D framework - with image manipulation

Tags: ipad, image-processing

I want to develop a graphics application for the iPad (ported from some existing code).  The application centers around creation/manipulation of a 2D image and the pixel level, but otherwise would look more like a 2D game than a standard 'business' application, so I could probably save a lot of time using a 2D game framework.

Ideally I think my best solution would be a 2D game engine that allows image manipulation.  Does such an engine exist?  I looked at the Corona SDK, but that doesn't support image processing.

Alternatively does there exist any OpenGL frameworks that include a widget set suitable for creating bespoke controls?